# Doxygen show enum defined values

Tags: c, enums, doxygen

There are some questions on how to show the auto-generated enum value, which doxygen apparently cannot do.

However, what I want to do is to show the *defined* enum value. Doxygen will actually to this in file overview but *not* in the actual enum spec. Consider this:

```
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************************
*   Board version values. Board version is provided by three signals in the PCB, which are treated like a 3-bit value. 
*****************************************************************************************************************************************************/
typedef enum _boardVer
{
    /// First prototype version
    board_REV_A = 0x07,
    /// Second prototype version
    board_REV_B = 0x03,
    /// Current pre-production version, will be production if no issues found
    board_REV_C = 0x05
} boardVer;
```

main.c tree item shows this, the explicitly defined values are shown as expected.

[image: main.c enum def]

However _boardVer item shows this:

[image: _boardVer item]

So .. How do I convince Doxygen to show the values in the detailed description as well?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Doxygen does not have the possibility to show the values (see also https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8256).

Comment: @albert 1.9.8. Based on discussion, they don't want to do it because not every value is necessarily explicitly defined and may contain macros and whatnot. To make things worse, the enum spec does not link back to the module overview that does in fact contain the explicit values, so you can easily walk away thinking the enum is 1, 2, 3 while in reality it's something completely different. It could/should be handled better, I guess I just need to add the value to the description.

Comment: Do you refer to the discussion in the mentioned issue or to another discussion? Thinking about the enum values possibility probably it would be better to have a setting that enables this possibility (and maybe even 2 commands `\enumvalues` and `\hideenumvalues` so that it can even be steered on the enum level). As written in the issue doxygen will not be able to calculate the value but only to repeat the given value).

Comment: @albert The github issue. The thing is that I don't *want* it to calculate anything, just display what I've explicitly defined, just like it does for the "Enumerations". Defaulting to null for values that have not been explicitly defined would work for me and probably for quite a few others, but that's not how it works. Linking back to the "Enumerations" would be good as well. 
I just added the explicit values to the description, that works albeit it's not very elegant.

Comment: So when I understand you correctly you want exactly what is done in the proposed patch https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8266 which I proposed in the above comment to extend a little bit

Comment: @albert Possibly, but I'm not holding my breath on getting that 3 year old request getting included. You could of course add improvements to it and submit it again in the chance someone will take it this time around.

Comment: I'm a bit less pessimistic / negative and I think that by adjusting the proposed pull request to the current master and adding the more flexible steering as indicated in my previous comment there is a reasonable chance of getting it included. So I updated the proposed pull request. Adjusting the proposed pull request also brings it again a bit more in focus.